# Extend enum or union type as generic

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a hook with generic type.
This generic type should be enum or union type because I want just allow some "operation" in this hook. (default: create,edit,update)

But I can't extend the enum/union type from an another place. (I want to add 'restore' option)

Implementation:

```
export type Operations = 'CREATE' | 'EDIT' | 'DELETE';

export const useMyHook = <T extends Operations>() => {
    const [operation, setOperation] = useState<T | undefined>()
….x
```

When in use:

```
export type ExtendedOperations = Operations | 'RESTORE';
const {x} = useMyHook<ExtendedOperations>()
```

> TS2344: Type  ExtendedOperations  does not satisfy the
> constraint  Operations  Type  "RESTORE"  is not assignable to type
>  Operations

How can I figure out this?
Thank you!

Comment: [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3Vd3N) should match your needs. If you need a detailed answer just let me know

Comment: thank you. But it looks like export const useMyHook = <T extends string>() =>

Comment: [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX1xON) is a looser approach